# Block Coordinate descent (BCD) a gradient-free method

Tags: optimization

in "Global Convergence of Block Coordinate Descent in Deep Learning" the authors claims that BCD is gradient-free method but in "Block-Cyclic Stochastic Coordinate Descent for Deep Neural Networks" authors calculate the gradient in the BCD algorithm.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Yes, I have been wondering about this too. I guess its not exactly gradient-free coordinate descent in this case.